# How do I create spaces between every four integers in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to take the following number:

```
423523420987
```

And convert it to this:

```
4235 2342 0987
```

It doesn't necessarily have to be an integer either. In fact, I would prefer it to be a string.

Comment: Are your numbers guaranteed to break evenly into groups of 4? If not, do you want the <4 group at the beginning (12 3456 7890) or the end (1234 5678 90)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [**`String::gsub`**](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000817) with a regular expression:

```
=> 'abcdefghijkl'.gsub(/.{4}(?=.)/, '\0 ')
'abcd efgh ijkl'
```

Comment: This is probably the fastest, Garrett's is easier to read, only because the regex that's required is simpler.

Answer (score 14):

```
class String
  def in_groups_of(n, sep=' ')
    chars.each_slice(n).map(&:join).join(sep)
  end
end

423523420987.to_s.in_groups_of(4)      # => '4235 2342 0987'
423523420987.to_s.in_groups_of(5, '-') # => '42352-34209-87'
```

Answer (score 4):

To expand on @Mark Byer's answer and @glenn mcdonald's comment, what do you want to do if the length of your string/number is not a multiple of 4?

```
'1234567890'.gsub(/.{4}(?=.)/, '\0 ')
# => "1234 5678 90"

'1234567890'.reverse.gsub(/.{4}(?=.)/, '\0 ').reverse
# => "12 3456 7890"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for padded zeros in case you have less than 12 or more than 12 numbers this will help you out:

```
irb(main):002:0> 423523420987.to_s.scan(/\d{4}/).join(' ')
=> "4235 2342 0987"
irb(main):008:0> ('%d' % 423523420987).scan(/\d{4}/).join(' ')
=> "4235 2342 0987"
```

Comment: Mark Byers' is probably the fastest, this is the prettiest, in my opinion.

Comment: The bit about “padded zeros” no loner applies after the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each digit and if the loop index mod 4 = 0 then place a space.

[Modulus in Ruby](http://marcricblog.blogspot.com/2007/11/ruby-modulus-operator-and-pols.html)