# Ruby: Insert spaces every X number of characters

Tags: ruby, string

In a ruby string, how can I insert a space every X number of characters?

As an example, I'd like to insert a space every 8 characters of a given string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create spaces between every four integers in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053328/how-do-i-create-spaces-between-every-four-integers-in-ruby)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
>> s = "1234567812345678123456781234567812345678"
=> "1234567812345678123456781234567812345678"
>> s.gsub(/(.{8})/, '\1 ')
=> "12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678 "
```

**Edit:** You could use positive lookahead to avoid adding an extra space at the end:

```
>> s.gsub(/(.{8})(?=.)/, '\1 \2')
=> "12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678 12345678"
```

Comment: Close. What about every 8 characters, but don't add a space at the end of the string?

Comment: just add a `strip!`. so it would turn into `s.gsub(/(.{8})/, '\1 ').strip!`

Comment: What if the string initially had leading or trailing spaces?

Comment: @Nabb: Then you could preprocess it w/ `s.gsub!(/^\s*|\s*$/,'')`

Comment: The canonical way to remove leading and trailing space is `s.strip!`

Answer (score 19):

Alternate solution:

```
s.scan(/.{1,8}/).join(' ')
```

`String#scan` will chunk it up for you (into spans of 8 characters - except for the last chunk, which may be shorter), and then `Array#join` will reunite the chunks with the appropriate character interspersed.