# How to insert tag every 5 characters in a Ruby String?

Tags: ruby, string, insert

I would like to insert a `<wbr>` tag every 5 characters.

**Input:** `s = 'HelloWorld-Hello guys'`

**Expected outcome:** `Hello<wbr>World<wbr>-Hell<wbr>o guys`

Comment: In Ruby you can treat a string like a character array. Maybe this helps in finding an solution.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
s = 'HelloWorld-Hello guys'
s.scan(/.{5}|.+/).join("<wbr>")
```

Explanation:

[Scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000812) groups all matches of the regexp into an array. The `.{5}` matches any 5 characters. If there are characters left at the end of the string, they will be matched by the `.+`. Join the array with your string

Answer (score 10):

There are several options to do this. If you just want to insert a delimiter string you can use [`scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000812) followed by `join` as follows:

```
s = '12345678901234567'
puts s.scan(/.{1,5}/).join(":")
# 12345:67890:12345:67
```

`.{1,5}` matches between 1 and 5 of "any" character, but since it's greedy, it will take 5 if it can. The allowance for taking less is to accomodate the last match, where there may not be enough leftovers.

Another option is to use [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000817), which allows for more flexible substitutions:

```
puts s.gsub(/.{1,5}/, '<\0>')
# <12345><67890><12345><67>
```

`\0` is a backreference to what group 0 matched, i.e. the whole match. So substituting with `<\0>` effectively puts whatever the regex matched in literal brackets.

If whitespaces are not to be counted, then instead of `.`, you want to match `\s*\S` (i.e. a non whitespace, possibly preceded by whitespaces).

```
s = '123 4 567  890   1 2 3 456 7  '
puts s.gsub(/(\s*\S){1,5}/, '[\0]')
# [123 4 5][67  890][   1 2 3 45][6 7]
```

#### Attachments

- [Source code and output on ideone.com](http://www.ideone.com/HCX5v)

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

  - [Finite Repetition, Greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)
  - [Character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
  - [Grouping and Backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
  - [Dot Matches (Almost) Any Character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)

Comment: I really like your different approaches and the explanations. +1

Comment: Very comprehensive Thank you very  much

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that is adapted from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168992/insert-something-every-x-number-of-characters-without-regex/3169285#3169285) to a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168992/insert-something-every-x-number-of-characters-without-regex/):

```
class String
  def in_groups_of(n, sep = ' ')
    chars.each_slice(n).map(&:join).join(sep)
  end
end

p 'HelloWorld-Hello guys'.in_groups_of(5,'<wbr>')
# "Hello<wbr>World<wbr>-Hell<wbr>o guy<wbr>s"
```

The result differs from your example in that the space counts as a character, leaving the final `s` in a group of its own. Was your example flawed, or do you mean to exclude spaces (whitespace in general?) from the character count?

---

To only count non-whitespace (“sticking” trailing whitespace to the last non-whitespace, leaving whitespace-only strings alone):

```
# count "hard coded" into regexp
s.scan(/(?:\s*\S(?:\s+\z)?){1,5}|\s+\z/).join('<wbr>')

# parametric count
s.scan(/\s*\S(?:\s+\z)?|\s+\z/).each_slice(5).map(&:join).join('<wbr>')
```

Comment: I want to vote to you  But I can't now  
thank you very much!!